# Image will display only via img tag

Tags: html, css

I want to assign an image as background of a  part in my website. However, the image is displayed only when I am using the img tag. Here is my code:

**html:**

```
<div class="menu_icon" />
```

**CSS:**

```
.menu_icon  {
      background-image: url(menu_1.png);
      height: 70px;
      width: 120px;
}
```

check the jsfiddle http://jsfiddle.net/sureshponnukalai/j3t208d3/

Many thanks

Comment: You close a div like so `<div> </div>` not `<div />`

Comment: It is working http://jsfiddle.net/sureshponnukalai/j3t208d3/

Comment: @SureshPonnukalai that's probably because jsFiddle / chrome in general fixes closing tags etc

Comment: try closing the `div` as `</div>` and check whether the image url has been specified right.

Comment: Please mark the correct answer (closing the div tag). This is the answer. If this still doesn't work it's because the path to your image is wrong.

Comment: I have already mentioned above that it works using the img tag so the path is correct. Nonetheless, closing the div tag does not help.

Comment: are you using same path? so html and css are in same folder??

Answer (score 2, accepted):

HTML:

```
<div class="menu_icon"></div>
```

CSS:

```
.menu_icon  {
      background-image: url(http://www.digitaldesktopwallpaper.com/wallpapers/denis-carl-flickr/005e.jpg);
      height: 70px;
      width: 120px;
      background-size: cover;
}
```

This *is* working - http://jsfiddle.net/9rxzcowm/1/

I would suggest you make sure your `div` is closed properly and your path to your image file is correct in relation to the `css` file you have

Comment: No problem, glad it's sorted :)

Answer (score 1):

You need to close the div

```
<div>...</div>
```

This should help.

Comment: Thank you cb0, but it still does not work... The image will display only via img tag

Answer (score -2):

To apply background image , try applying the below method

html

```
<div>...</div>
```

css

```
div{    
    background-image:url('image_path');
}
```

although, this too would result in repetitive display.

Comment: No need to change it to all `div` tags, the `div` in question has a class on it

Answer (score -3):

Hmmm you need add the ""

This: background-image: url(menu_1.png);
For this: background-image: url('menu_1.png');

Comment: You don't, it's the fact the `div` isn't closed

Comment: did you closed div and add the  ' ' ??